# How do you make a new website at plesk at httpdocs

Tags: webserver, http, domain, plesk

This is what my boss wants me to do in our plesk enviroment:

Website being at document root(i think?):

[image]

This site is in the smth else folder of the httpdocs of another site:

[image]

On file manager it looks like this:

[image]

I have searched so deep in the documentation and nothing helps. Tech of company who works away from here tells me I am supposed to know this but there is no info online on the subject.

Only thing I have found is that this is supposed to be done by creating new subscriptions but the company senior dev says it's not. ([my source on that](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000563974-How-to-create-new-DocumentRoot-location-for-new-domain-name))

When creating a domain I can only use other already created sites on the location of website files field and  I cant clear that field:

[image]

So, How do you make a new website at Plesk at httpdocs?

Comment: Plesk is used to create virtualhosts for each domain/subdomain you have defined. Each site should have its own, separate storage. Can you describe in clearer detail exactly what you're trying to do....? Are you trying to set a home directory for a site but can't change it because it won't let you?

Comment: @Kinnectus Im trying to create a new domain lets say example.com with its own storage. Already made said site and ready to upload it , just cant create a separate storage for it.

Comment: It should create a new virtualhost for your domain, including storage, when you create a new website. The storage will be under `/var/www/vhosts/<domain_name>/httpdocs`. I run Plesk and if I go to "Websites & Domains" > Click `Add Domain` > it takes me toa  page where I can choose the domain, create a new workspace or use an existing workspace and configure the additional details like user account and SSL.